# What is this behavior in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, svg, layers

I copy pasted one image icon from **Adobe XD** to create a vector of it in adobe illustrator.
But my Ai is behaving differently, it is having the icon in the background everywhere.

Seems like the hidden background or something. Can anyone please tell me what is this behaviour here?

It never happened before.

[image: Reference Video]

Answer (score 2):

It's a **pattern fill**.

Then in `Preferences > General` the `Transform Pattern Tiles` is **not** checked. This results in what you are seeing.... as the object moves, the internal pattern does *not* move.

Essentially "Transform Pattern Tiles" is *not* checked somewhere - either in the Prefs, the Transform panel, Properties Panel... somewhere.